# CMake exclude dir with a regular expression

Tags: cmake

I want to exclude some dirs from building by using the following:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE Foo_SOURCES "*.c" "*.cpp")

# Enter the excluded directories here
set (excludeDirName "")
list (APPEND excludeDirName "/test")
list (APPEND excludeDirName "/std")

set (Foo_SOURCES_FILES "")
foreach (_sourceFile ${Foo_SOURCES})
    foreach (_excludeDirName ${excludeDirName})
        if (NOT "${_sourceFile}" MATCHES "(.*)${_excludeDirName}(.*)")
            list (APPEND Foo_SOURCES_FILES ${_sourceFile})
        endif ()
    endforeach ()
endforeach ()
```

Sadly no dirs are excluded.
I think it depends on using a regex on a file / list mix.

Comment: While you append source files under `if()` branch, that `if()` is executed in the `foreach` loop. That is, if at least on **one of the iteration** the condition is evaluated as TRUE, then a source file is appended. E.g. if a source file contains `/test` then it doesn't contain `/std`, so it is added in the `/std` iteration. And vice versa.

Comment: Wow. I think you are right.
Any suggestion how to solve this problem?
Can I feed the whole list into the regex without the second for loop?

Comment: Expression `(/test|/std)` would express matching to `/test` or `/std`, so iteration won't be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of inner loop

```
foreach (_excludeDirName ${excludeDirName})
    if (NOT "${_sourceFile}" MATCHES "(.*)${_excludeDirName}(.*)")
        list (APPEND Foo_SOURCES_FILES ${_sourceFile})
    endif ()
endforeach ()
```

is that it matches a file **multiple times**, and the file is added when **any of matches** is failed. But you need the opposite behaviore: the file should be added only when **all matches** are failed.

You may rewrite the loop as:

```
set(is_matched FALSE)
foreach (_excludeDirName ${excludeDirName})
    if ("${_sourceFile}" MATCHES "(.*)${_excludeDirName}(.*)")
       set(is_matched TRUE) 
    endif ()
endforeach ()
if (NOT is_matched)
    list (APPEND Foo_SOURCES_FILES ${_sourceFile})
endif()
```

that it will firstly checks all matches, and a file will be added only after none match is succeed.

Alternatively, you may construct regular expression which attempt to match all directories at once, using `|` operator:

```
# Join list of directories into the string using '|' delimiter
list(JOIN excludeDirName '|' exclude_dir_regex)

foreach (_sourceFile ${Foo_SOURCES})
    # This would replace the inner loop.
    if (NOT "${_sourceFile}" MATCHES "(.*)(${exclude_dir_regex})(.*)")
       list (APPEND Foo_SOURCES_FILES ${_sourceFile})
    endif ()
 endfor ()
```

Of course, the last approach would work only if directories doesn't contain characters, special for regular expressions (like `.` or `(`).

The last approach could be implemented even without loops using [list(FILTER)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#filter):

```
# Join list of directories into the string using '|' delimiter
list(JOIN excludeDirName '|' exclude_dir_regex)

# Make output list of files same as input list...
set (Foo_SOURCES_FILES FOO_SOURCES)
# ... and filter out unneeded files
list(FILTER Foo_SOURCES_FILES EXCLUDE "${exclude_dir_regex}")
```

Comment: Thank a lot. I used your first solution to maintain flexibility with the directory names.